# SQL - Add new column with outputs as values

Tags: sql-server

Just wondering how I might go about adding the ouputted results as a new column to an exsisting table.
What I'm tryng to do is extract the date from a string which is in another column. I have the below code to do this:

**Code**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric
(
  @strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @intAlpha INT
  SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)
  BEGIN
    WHILE @intAlpha > 0
    BEGIN
      SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
      SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
    END
  END
  RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO
Now use the function as


SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric(column_name) 
from table_name
```

**The issue** is that I want the result to be placed in a new column in an exsisting table. I have tried the below code but no luck.

```
ALTER TABLE [Data_Cube_Data].[dbo].[DB_Test]
ADD reportDated nvarchar NULL;



insert into [DB].[dbo].[DB_Test](reportDate)
SELECT 
         (SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric(FileNamewithDate) from [DB].[dbo].[DB_Test])
```

Comment: are you sure about the mysql tag? This looks ore like SQL SERVER

Comment: Are you sure the DBMS that you are using MySQL?

Comment: Besides the rdms, You need to UPDATE not INSERT

Comment: apologies, its SQL server

Comment: I would strongly suggest rewriting that function; it's a multi-line scalar function (which are known to perform poorly at times) *and* it has a `WHILE` (which *do* perform terribly). If you are writing a function, use an inline table value function. 2019 does support inlining of scalar functions, but the above won't be inlined.

Comment: Also you define `reportDated` as an `nvarchar(1)`, but your function returns `varchar(256)`; that's a significant data type mismatch.

Comment: What is the goal of your function here? To just retain the numerical characters of the string? What characters can the string contain? Is it just A-z and 0-9, or ca it contain *any* character (within your collation's base code page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax should be an UPDATE, not an INSERT, because you want to *update* existing rows, not *insert* new ones:

```
UPDATE Data_Cube_Data.dbo.DB_Test -- you don't need square bracket noise
  SET reportDate = dbo.udf_GetNumeric(FileNamewithDate);
```

But yeah, I agree with the others, the function looks like the result of a "how can I make this object the least efficient thing in my entire database?" contest. Here's a better alternative:

```
-- better, set-based TVF with no while loop
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tvf_GetNumeric
(@strAlphaNumeric varchar(256))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    WITH cte(n) AS 
    (
      SELECT TOP (256) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
      FROM   sys.all_objects
    )
    SELECT output = COALESCE(STRING_AGG(
           SUBSTRING(@strAlphaNumeric, n, 1), '')
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY n), '')
    FROM   cte
    WHERE  SUBSTRING(@strAlphaNumeric, n, 1) LIKE '%[0-9]%'
  );
```

Then the query is:

```
UPDATE t
  SET t.reportDate = tvf.output
  FROM dbo.DB_Test AS t
  CROSS APPLY dbo.tvf_GetNumeric(t.FileNamewithDate) AS tvf;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d8fd310c23888d0bd4241ccd8f2dc039) that shows this has the same behavior as your existing function.

Comment: I am receiving the following error **"Invalid column name 'reportDated'"**

Comment: @PythonBeginner (1) your question has `ADD reportDated` to the table but then `reportDate` in the insert, so I'm not sure which one you really did. (2) you need a GO between the alter table and the update, otherwise SQL Server will try to parse the column reference before the alter happens.

Answer (score 1):

### The function

As i mentioned in the comments, I would strongly suggest rewriting the function, it'll perform *terribly*. Multi-line table value function can perform poorly, and you also have a `WHILE` which **will** perform awfully. SQL is a set based language, and so you should be using set based methods.

There are a couple of alternatives though:

#### Inlinable Scalar Function

SQL Server 2019 can inline function, so you could inline the above. I do, however, assume that your value can *only* contain the characters A-z and 0-9. if it can contain other characters, such as periods (`.`), commas (`,`), quotes (`"`) or even white space ( ), or your not on 2019 then don't use this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric (@strAlphaNumeric varchar(256))
RETURNS varchar(256) AS 
BEGIN
    RETURN TRY_CONVERT(int,REPLACE(TRANSLATE(LOWER(@strAlphaNumeric),'abcdefghigclmnopqrstuvwxyz',REPLICATE('|',26)),'|',''));
END;
GO

SELECT dbo.udf_GetNumeric('abs132hjsdf');
```

The `LOWER` is there *in case* you are using a case sensitive collation.

#### Inline Table Value Function

This is the better solution in my mind, and doesn't have the caveats of the above.

It uses a Tally to split the data into individual characters, and then only reaggregate the characters that are a digit. Note that I *assume* you are using SQL Server 2017+ here:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION udf_GetNumeric; --Need to drop as it's a scalar function at the moment
GO
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumeric (@strAlphaNumeric varchar(256))
RETURNS table AS 
RETURN
    WITH N AS (
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT TOP (LEN(@strAlphaNumeric))
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2,  N N3, N N4)
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN V.C LIKE '[0-9]' THEN V.C END,'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY T.I) AS strNumeric
    FROM Tally T
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@strAlphaNumeric,T.I,1)))V(C);
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.udf_GetNumeric('abs132hjsdf');
```

### Your table

You define `reportDated` as `nvarchar`; this means `nvarchar(1)`. Your function, however, returns a `varchar(256)`; this will *rarely* fit in an `nvarchar(1)`.

Define the column properly:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DB_Test] ADD reportDated varchar(256) NULL;
```

If you've already created the column then do the following:

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DB_Test] ALTER COLUMN reportDated varchar(256) NULL;
```

I note, however, that the column is called "dated", which implies a date value, but it's a `(n)varchar`; that sounds like a flaw.

### Updating the column

Use an `UPDATE` statement. Depending on the solution this would one of the following:

```sql
--Scalar function
UPDATE [dbo].[DB_Test]
SET reportDated = dbo.udf_GetNumeric(FileNamewithDate);

--Table Value Function
UPDATE DBT
SET reportDated = GN.strNumeric
FROM [dbo].[DB_Test] DBT
     CROSS APPLY dbo.udf_GetNumeric(FileNamewithDate);
```